# Navigation coming back to the previous view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to navigate to a `ViewController` but after a second the `ViewController` just disappears and the old one shows.

Here is the function for the navigation:

```
private func NavigateToManagerMenu() {
    let MainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    guard let MainNavigationVC = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MianNavigationController") as? MainNavigationController else{return}
    present(MainNavigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

it called from the button Action:

```
@IBAction func ArrowAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if mode == "signup"{
        if CheckSignUp(){
            SignUp()
            NavigateToManagerMenu()
        }
    }
    if mode == "login"{
        if CheckLogin(){
            LogIn()
            NavigateToManagerMenu()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something in second VC's `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` that might cause that VC to disappear?

Comment: no, I have only 3 buttons there

Comment: What does `SignUp()` do? And can you show the code inside `MainNavigationController`?

Comment: SighUp() and LogIn() just handle with the Firebase, 
MainNavigationController:

import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

Comment: It would be good to see more of the code related to MainNavigationController. IS this just a navigation controller? A navigation controller does not have inherently have a viewController in it. It would make more sense to instantiate your Navigation Controller, then push your view controller to it ( navigationController.pushViewcontroller(MainViewController) ), then finally present your navigation controller which will then contain your view controller.

Comment: its crush with  navigationController.pushViewcontroller(MainViewController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `dismiss(animated: , completion: )` is being called in your code somewhere in the presenting or presented viewControllers.
Just to check it try to push MainNavigationVC instead of presenting it.

Or try commenting SignUp() and LogIn() calls.

Comment: Try to present a new ViewController. Use `present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: you were right, I missed one dismiss.
thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to  caputure the screen using "capture interface" option in Xcode 10.1  and check the viewcontroller is hiding under any view or not.